# Binding DataGrid columns to a SQL database doesnt work

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, database, datagrid

Im trying to do that SQL type "Date" displayed in Datagrid like date, not "Datetime".
I cant understand what specifically im doing wrong. But It doesnt work.

```css
cmd.CommandText="SELECT Patient.Secondname as 'Фамилия', Patient.Name as 'Имя', Patient.Patronymic as 'Отчество', Patient.Adress as 'Адрес', Patient.Telephone as 'Номер телефона' FROM Patient";
 cmd.CommandType=CommandType.Text;
 adp=new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
 dtPat=new DataTable("Schedule");
 adp.Fill(dtPat);
```

And:

```js
<DataGrid Name = "ScheduleCommon"
 Margin = "2,0,4,0"
 RenderTransformOrigin = "-0.21,0.4"
 AutoGenerateColumns = "False"
 EnableRowVirtualization = "True"
 ItemsSource = "{Binding}">
   < DataGrid.Columns >
   < DataGridTextColumn Header = "ФИО" Binding = "{Binding apt.Name}"/>
   < DataGridTextColumn Header = "Специализация" Binding = "{Binding apt.Specialisation}"/>
   < DataGridTextColumn Header = "Дата" Binding = "{Binding apt.WorkDay, StringFormat=dd MM yyyy}"/>
   < DataGridTextColumn Header = "С" Binding = "{Binding apt.TimeBegin}"/>
   < DataGridTextColumn Header = "До"
 Binding = "{Binding apt.TimeEnd}"/>
   < /DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid >
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the property window, on the right of the property "Binding", you have a little square on wich you can click and select "Create binding". Then click on "more paremeter" and then you can choose your string format

For example in this case :

```
StringFormat=\{0:d\}}"
```